# Text hyperlinked fading into image also hyperlinked

Tags: css, html, css-animations

At the moment the text is hyperlinked and when it fades to the other image the link is no longer there can you have the second image (the one it fades into linked)

It seems to only hyperlink the text then when to image appears the link disappears.

Here is my code
Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<style>
    div{
        background-image: url("http://#.com");
        height: 200px;
        width:200px;
      transition: background-image 0.7s ease-in-out;
              transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
    }
    #hello:hover{
        font-size:0px;
        background-image: url('http://#.com');

    }

    #hmv:hover{

        font-size:0px;
        background-image: url("http://#.com");

    }

    p{ text-align:center;font-size:3em;}
</style>

<div id="hello">

   <br>

<a href="#"><p>Pottery</p></a>
</div>
<br>
<div id="hmv">

   <br>

<a href="#"><p>Silver</p></a>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you give any demo url. Then more better for clarify.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? could you please clarify

Comment: What's the issue here? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OgGXvr

Comment: http://www.sololearn.com/app/css/playground/WN44je6ERUoL/ here is the test

Comment: When you hover over the text the text disappears and the image changes then the link is no longer there so there is no link anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are changing the font size to 0px on hover, that's why text is disappearing, i commented out that font size line, check it out.

```
#hello:hover{
   /* font-size:0px; */
    background-image: url('http://#.com');

}

#hmv:hover{

   /* font-size:0px; */
    background-image: url("http://#.com");

}
```

Comment: That works is it possible to have the text move to the bottom of the image to show the image more?

Comment: Yes, you can give padding to the p tag, like this, 
    `#hello:hover p,
    #hmv:hover p{
        padding-top: 50%;
    }`

Comment: One more thing can you change the text color when hovered?

Comment: Sure, just add `#hmv:hover p{ padding-top: 50%; color: #2c2c2c; }` in the same rule above